# Unable to apply padding or margin to "lead" class <p> element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

I'm currently building my first website using the bootstrap framework and  would like to apply 30px of padding between the 'lead' paragraph and the responsive image for the following Blog page I'm writing. However the CSS doesn't seem to apply either padding or margin to the "lead" class p element. It was working okay yesterday but I've been fiddling with the layout since then, so I'm not sure why this rule isn't firing now?

Similarly, I wrapped 'continue reading...' in a 'float-right' class yesterday which worked correctly, however again today since fiddling with the CSS it has defaulted to the left side of the column so that I have had to apply `text-align: right; in CSS. What is causing these anomalies? I am very new to Bootstrap and website building in general and realize that my code may be disorganized or missing crucial information, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Jon

http://www.jonhowlett.uk/blog.html

HTML:-

```
 <div id="blog">    
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!--heading-->
            <h1>Latest Posts</h1>
            <!--list of posts-->
            <article><!--use to semantically markup each blog post, forum post, newspaper article etc., -->
            <h2><a href="#">Blog Post 1</a></h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="group 1 col-sm-6 col-md-6"><!--grouped together category and tags into one column-->
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> <a href="#">Open Folder</a>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> <a href="#">Bookmark 1</a>,<a href="#">Bookmark 2</a>, <a href="#">Bookmark 3</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group2 col-sm-6 col-md-6"><!--grouped together total comments and posted date--><!--GROUP2 is required to align both the total comments and published date to right in case of tablets and desktops-->

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> <a href="singlepost.html#comments">20 Comments</a>                             
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Friday 2nd October 2015                       
                    </div>

                    <a href="singlepost1.html"><img src="images/blogpost1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>

                    <br />

                    <p class="lead"><!--LEAD class increases font size and makes it bold-->Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>

                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-arrow-right"></span>
                    <p class="text-right"><!--TEXT-RIGHT class to align right...-->
                        <a href="singlepost1.html" class="text-right">
                            continue reading<span class="span_space"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></span>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <hr class="hr"></hr>
            <article><!--use to semantically markup each blog post, forum post, newspaper article etc., -->
            <h2><a href="#">Blog Post 2</a></h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="group 1 col-sm-6 col-md-6"><!--grouped together category and tags into one column-->
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> <a href="#">Open Folder</a>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> <a href="#">Bookmark 1</a>,<a href="#">Bookmark 2</a>, <a href="#">Bookmark 3</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group2 col-sm-6 col-md-6"><!--grouped together total comments and posted date--><!--GROUP2 is required to align both the total comments and published date to right in case of tablets and desktops-->

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> <a href="singlepost.html#comments">20 Comments</a>                             
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Friday 2nd October 2015                       
                    </div>

                    <a href="singlepost2.html"><img src="images/blogpost2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>

                    <br />

                    <p class="lead"><!--LEAD class increases font size and makes it bold-->Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>

                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-arrow-right"></span>
                    <p class="text-right"><!--TEXT-RIGHT class to align right...-->
                        <a href="singlepost2.html" class="text-right">
                            continue reading<span class="span_space"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></span>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <hr class="hr"></hr>
            <article><!--use to semantically markup each blog post, forum post, newspaper article etc., -->
            <h2><a href="#">Blog Post 3</a></h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="group 1 col-sm-6 col-md-6"><!--grouped together category and tags into one column-->
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> <a href="#">Open Folder</a>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bookmark"></span> <a href="#">Bookmark 1</a>,<a href="#">Bookmark 2</a>, <a href="#">Bookmark 3</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group2 col-sm-6 col-md-6"><!--grouped together total comments and posted date--><!--GROUP2 is required to align both the total comments and published date to right in case of tablets and desktops-->

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> <a href="singlepost.html#comments">20 Comments</a>                             
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Friday 2nd October 2015                       
                    </div>

                    <a href="singlepost3.html"><img src="images/blogpost3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>

                    <br />

                    <p class="lead"><!--LEAD class increases font size and makes it bold-->Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>

                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-arrow-right"></span>
                    <p class="text-right"><!--TEXT-RIGHT class to align right...-->
                        <a href="singlepost3.html" class="text-right">
                            continue reading<span class="span_space"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></span>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>              
            <ul class="pager"> 
                <li class="previous">
                    <a href="#">Older</a>
                </li> 
                <li class="next">
                    <a href="#">Newer</a>
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <!-- Other widgets -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
#blog_jumbotron .jumbotron {
background-image: url(images/blogpost_jumbotron3.jpg);
}

#blog h1 {
font-family:'Roboto', arial;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#blog h2 {
  font-family: 'Questrial', arial;
  font-size: 30px;
     padding-bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

#blog h2 a {
  color: #D35F45;
}

#blog img {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#blog p {
  font-family: 'Questrial', arial;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#blog .lead {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #303046;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

#blog .img-responsive {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

#blog .text-right {
  color: #D35F45;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: right;
}

#blog .pager a {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 2px solid #7C7C7C;
  color: #7C7C7C;
  font-family: 'Questrial', arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#blog .pager a:hover {
  background-color: #D35F45;
  border: 2px solid #D35F45;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


#blog a img {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: can you put up fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oq6utfmw/

Comment: check this - added padding above p https://jsfiddle.net/oq6utfmw/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `lead` class's css:-

```
position:relative;
top:50px;
padding-bottom:50px;
```

First two lines are for shifting the paragraph and the third line is for shifting the rest of the document equally i.e. if you want to increase the amount of distance from top then you also have to update the same amount in `padding-bottom` to maintain its distance with the rest of the down-below content.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
#blog_jumbotron .jumbotron {
  background-image: url(images/blogpost_jumbotron3.jpg);
}

#blog h1 {
  font-family:'Roboto', arial;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#blog h2 {
  font-family: 'Questrial', arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

#blog h2 a {
  color: #D35F45;
}

#blog img {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#blog p {
  font-family: 'Questrial', arial;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#blog .lead {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #303046;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

#blog .img-responsive {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

#blog .text-right {
  color: #D35F45;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: right;
}

#blog .pager a {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 2px solid #7C7C7C;
  color: #7C7C7C;
  font-family: 'Questrial', arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#blog .pager a:hover {
  background-color: #D35F45;
  border: 2px solid #D35F45;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}


#blog a img {
  float: left;
}
.next
{
    float:right;
 margin-top:-19px;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/oq6utfmw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You cant apply 30px of padding between the 'lead' paragraph and the responsive image because the `img` is in floating mode, the lead paragraph and the image becomes one block. `float` elements float around your paragraph, so in your case the padding goes around the image.